# Delete cell if it contains < 3 characters

Tags: excel, numbers, character, cells

As the title suggests, I'd like to delete a cell (delete the text) if the number of characters  in the cells is < 3.

For example

Row1 Row2 SN DWD

124 411 1  123

32    231 01 23

Here, I'd like "SN", "1", "32", "01" and "23" to all be made into blank cells.

Comment: "cells"? Is the Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean Excel

```
Sub ClearCellsWithLessThan3Chars()
 Dim cell As Range
 For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If (Len(cell.Text) < 3) Then
       cell.Clear
    End If
 Next
End Sub
```